# Remove values from NUL separated file

Tags: text-processing, perl, null

I have an array of values `v` that I want to remove from the file `f`. `f` is NUL delimited. How do I proceed? I tried using `sd`, but it [didn't work](https://github.com/chmln/sd/issues/53).

Example:

I have this file:

```
# cat -v $attic
^@this is 1.
this is 2.
this is 3.
^@hi
^@blue boy
```

And this variable `$i`:

```
# cat -v <<<"$i"
this is 1.
this is 2.
this is 3.
```

I want a command that removes `$i` from that file, resulting in:

```
^@hi
^@blue boy
```

I have tried `FROM="$i" perl -pi -e 's/\0\Q$ENV{FROM}\E//g' "$attic"`, but it doesn't work if `$i` is multiline. I tried `FROM="$i" perl -pi0 -e 's/\0\Q$ENV{FROM}\E//g' "$attic"` but this didn't do anything.

Comment: Please give us an example. There are loads of tools that can deal with NULLs, but we can't help you parse data you don't show us. [Edit] your question and add a few lines from your input file and the output you need from that input.

Comment: @terdon Is this good enough?

Comment: Not really :). Please paste the actual file, with the nulls so we can use it to test our solutions. Then show us the output you would want from that file.

Comment: @terdon now? That is the actual file, btw:))

Comment: @terdon (`^@` means the NUL char)

Comment: Yes, I know `^@` is the NUL, but if I want to test my solution, I will need to copy your text, then convert the `^@` to NULs in order to be able to use it. If you just paste the text directly, without `cat -v`, then I can use it and test my answers.And will the patterns always be full words or should `b` match `ball`? Basically, you need to give us an example that actually represents what you need to do. That way, we can see if our solution does what you need. So we need exact input and required output.

Comment: I removed the shells from the title and tags since it seems like you're just processing the file with perl. Let us know if you need a solution for a specific shell (and how that shell is involved). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention `zsh`, you could do:

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
mapfile[$attic]=${(pj:\0:)"${(0@)mapfile[$attic]}":#$i}
```

- `$mapfile` in the `zsh/mapfile` module is a special associative array that maps file names to their content.
- `"${(0@)var}"`: splits `$var` on NULs (and with `@` inside quotes preserves empty elements like `"$@"`).
- `${array:#pattern}`. removes the elements that match the pattern. Here the content of `$i` is taken literally, you'd need `$~i` for it to be taken as a pattern (or enable the `globsubst` option).
- `${(j:string:)array}`: joins the elements of the array with `string`. With `p`, `\0` is converted to NUL. (note that the `0` parameter expansion flag above can also be written `ps:\0:`).

You can get something similar with `perl` with:

```
FROM=$i perl -0lni -e 'print if $_ ne $ENV{FROM}' -- "$attic"
```

The difference being that `perl` will add a NUL at the end if there was not one already (and the usual problems with`-i` (breaking links, not preserving all metadata...)).

A closer equivalent would be:

```
FROM=$i perl -0777 -F'\0' -pi -e '
  $_ = join "\0", grep {$_ ne $ENV{FROM}} @F' -- "$attic"
```

Your

> ```
> FROM="$i" perl -pi0 -e 's/\0\Q$ENV{FROM}\E//g' "$attic"
> ```

doesn't work because:

- in `-pi0`: the `0` is taken as the argument to `-i` (the backup filename suffix)
- even if you had written `-0pi`, that couldn't have worked as that tells `perl` to process NUL-*terminated* records, so the record (`$_`) will have the NUL at the end, not beginning. Use `-0777` for `perl` to process the input as one record containing the whole input.

Comment: Thanks! Your perl solution works flawlessly. I gather -l0 makes it process NUL-started records? Does this load the whole file into memory? And why doesn't my `            FROM="$i" perl -0777 -pi -e 's/(\0|\A)\Q$ENV{FROM}\E(?<sep>\0|\Z)/$+{sep}/gm' "$attic"` replace all occurrences of `$i`? (It replaces some, but not all. I can't figure out how it decides how many to delete.)

Comment: btw I had to use `perl -pi -e 's/\0\Z//' "$attic"` to clean up the extra NUL it sometimes left.

Comment: @HappyFace because each replacement eats both the NUL before and after the match, so when perl resumes searching for the next match, it won't find the immediately following match because of NUL before it missing. You'd need to use a look-ahead operator that don't _eat_ the NULs but still check they're there.

Comment: @HappyFace, `-l0` would set the output record separator to `\0`. Same as `$\ = "\0";`, but here, I'm using `-0l`. `-0` sets the input record delimiter (`$/ = "\0"`) and `-l` sets the output record separator to the same value as the input record separator (`$\ = $/`) and also causes the IRS to be stripped on input.

Comment: @HappyFace The `-0l` approach reads one NUL delimited record at a time so won't load the whole file in memory if it's larger than `perl`'s internal buffer size. `-0777` is the slurp mode so will load the whole file in memory (like that `sd` does btw).

Comment: How can I use another char instead of NUL? (How do I set those `$/` `$/`?) (git and hg didn't like those NUL bytes :( )

Comment: @HappyFace, see `perldoc perlrun` for details about options and `perldoc perlvar` for details about the special variables like `$/`. In any case, revision control systems don't have issues with any byte value in the content of the file they track, they should be able to deal with any type of file.

Comment: They see any file with NUL as binary, and their merging algorithms don’t work on binary files. I tried forcing them to treat those files as text, but I could not succeed. (I asked about it on Stackoverflow.)

Comment: Ah, OK I thought you were implying they couldn't _store_ those files. Yes, a text file, by the POSIX definition at least can't have NUL characters.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your input data, and assuming your file is small enough to fit in memory, this might work for you:

```
$ export i
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/\Q$ENV{i}\E\n?//g' file 
hi
blue boy
```

The `-0777` causes `perl` to slurp the whole file into memory. The `$ENV{var}` is perl's way of accessing exported environment variables. So `$ENV{i}` will get the value for the exported variable `i`. The `s/old/new/g` will replace `old` with `new` globally. The `\Q` and `\E` ensure that the pattern isn't interpreted as a regular expression. Finally, the `\n?` is needed since the shell will eat newlines from the ends of variables when assigning the output of a command substitution (e.g. `var=$(printf 'foo\n')`), so `$i` might not actually include the final newline.

Note that this will also match substrings. So if `i` is `foo` and your file contains `foolish`, then the `foo` will be removed leaving `ish`. If you don't want that, you can use:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\Q$ENV{i}\E(\n|\b)//g' file
```

Testing on your example (after replacing `^@` with `\0`):

```
$ cat -v file
^@this is 1.
this is 2.
this is 3.
^@hi
^@blue boy

$ export i="$(printf 'this is 1.\nthis is 2.\nthis is 3.\n')"

$ perl -0777 -pe 's/\Q$ENV{i}\n?\E//g' file 
hi
blue boy
```

Of course, this assumes that `$i` has no trailing newline. I can't tell if it does or not since `cat <<<"$i"` would add one even if it didn't.

If you need to do this for a shell array, you can do:

```
for i in "${foo[@]}"; do 
    export i
    perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\b\Q$ENV{i}\E(\n|\b)//g' file 
done
```

***Important***: note the `-i` in the example above. This edits the file in place, so back it up before testing.

Comment: Thanks! How do I find `-007` in `perldoc perlrun`? BTW, I didn't know pasting preserves NUL. `$i` also does contain `\n`, and it needs to match the whole string between two NULs. I'm currently using `FROM="$i" perl -007 -pi -e 's/(\0|\A)\Q$ENV{FROM}\E//gm' "$attic" `, but this has the bug that it doesn't check for the ending `\0`.

Comment: @HappyFace yeah, that's kind of why it's so important to give examples that accurately reproduce your issue. I can't debug stuff I cannot see :/ If you edit your question with an actual example that we can use for testing I can try and play with it some more.

Comment: Thanks, I debugged it myself to reach the perfect (:-? :D) `FROM="$i" perl -007 -pi -e 's/(\0|\A)\Q$ENV{FROM}\E(?<sep>\0|\Z)/$+{sep}/gm' "$attic"`.

Comment: How do I found the docs for `-007`?

Comment: @HappyFace it's in `man perlrun`. Try `man perlrun | sed -En '/^\s+-0/,/^\s+-a/p`. Also see [How exactly does perl's -0 option work?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/192492)

Comment: `The special value 00 will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph mode. Any value 0400 or

above will cause Perl to slurp files whole, but by convention the value 0777 is the one
normally used for this purpose.` ?

Comment: I changed `-007` to `-0777` and everything seems to be ok. I suggest using that? It's more readable.

Comment: `m` doesn't make sense here. `m` is for `^` and `$` to match at the start/end of each line inside the subject.

Comment: You'd probably want `\Q$ENV{i}\E` for the content of `$i` not to be taken as a RE

Comment: The shell doesn't strip trailing newlines. It's just command substitution that does (`$(cmd)`). The OP's `$i` seems to have a trailing newline.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks. Should be better now. The `m` was from a previous version where I was using `.`.

Comment: Note that `m` does not affect the behaviour of `.`. `s` does